# my x and y values ' have different dimensions.' how to solve?

Tags: python, graph

i am trying to graph a function using the following code in python, for my class's homework assignment:

```
%matplotlib inline
import nbconvert
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from math import exp
Eg=1.1         # eV  Bandgap of Silicon\n",
er=11.9        # relative permitivity of Si\n",
eo=8.854E-12   # F/m\n",
Nc=2.8e19      # cm-3\n",
Nv=1.16e19     # cm-2\n",
k=8.617e-5     # eV/K  \n",
kJ=1.38e-23    # J/K\n",
e=1.602e-19
phiM=4.2       # eV\n",
chiSi=4.01     # eV\n",
Na=5e16        # cm-3\n",
PhiBP=Eg-(phiM-chiSi)
PhiBN=phiM-chiSi
print ('barrier height = ', PhiBP, 'eV')
Nav=Na/Nv
L=np.log(Nav)
#print(L)
Evf=-L*k*300
Ecf=Eg-Evf
#print(Evf)
Vo=(PhiBN+Ecf)
print ('Vo=', Vo, 'V')
ee=er*eo
eNa=e*Na*1000000
eev=2*ee*Vo
w2=eev/eNa
print(w2)
W=math.sqrt(w2)
W2=W*1000000000
#W=(2*er*eo*Vo/(e*Na))**0.5
print ('W= ', W, 'm')
print ('W=', W2, 'nm')
Jo=30*(300**2)*np.exp(-0.8/(k*300)) # Units here are A cm-2
print ('Jo=', Jo, 'A/cm^2')
Vvals=np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
def J(V):    # This defines your function (equation) for calculating J vs V\n",
  # *** WRITE YOUR FORMULA FOR J IN TERMS OF V HERE\n",
  J=Jo*(np.exp(e*V/(k*300))-1)
  return J,

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.semilogy(Vvals,(J(Vvals)), 'ro')
ax1.set(xlabel='Voltage (V)', ylabel='Current Density', title='Schottky diode J-V Semilog')
ig, ax2 = plt.subplots()      # Initializes second plot\n",
ax2.plot(Vvals,J(Vvals), 'ro') # Creates linear plot\n",
x2.set(xlabel='Voltage (V)', ylabel='Current Density J', title='Schottky diode J-V Linear')
plt.show()
```

when i get to the lines with ax1, i'm told that my x and y values 'have different shapes,' even though one is a function of the other so they should have the same number of plot points. how do i fix this?

i tried to make a log graph and linear graph of the same function, but was told
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (400,) and (1, 400)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake: on Line45 (return of the function), you wrote "return J,". Apparently, that messed up the value returned.

You wrote:

```
#----------------------Your code--------------------------------
def J(V):    # This defines your function (equation) for calculating J vs V\n",
  # *** WRITE YOUR FORMULA FOR J IN TERMS OF V HERE\n",
  J=Jo*(np.exp(e*V/(k*300))-1)
  return J,  #<-------------------That comma messed with the list

#------------------------The fix---------------------------------
def J(V):    # This defines your function (equation) for calculating J vs V\n",
  # *** WRITE YOUR FORMULA FOR J IN TERMS OF V HERE\n",
  J=Jo*(np.exp(e*V/(k*300))-1)
  return J  #<------------- Comma removed
```

When you put the "return J," (with the comma) you returned this (you can try it with print)

```
(array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         ................................................................
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),)
```

After fixing it with "return J" without the comma, you will return this

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
.................................
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Which is the list that i guess you wanted for the plot

However, i recommend you to check the formula again, since the function gives only 0 values, as you see above. I'm not sure if this was the result you intended.

Also, on line 50 you called wrong the ax2 variable for the plot

```
#----------------------Your code--------------------------------
ig, ax2 = plt.subplots()      # Initializes second plot\n",
ax2.plot(Vvals,J(Vvals), 'ro') # Creates linear plot\n",
x2.set(xlabel='Voltage (V)', ylabel='Current Density J', title='Schottky diode J-V Linear')
plt.show()
#------------------------The fix---------------------------------
ig, ax2 = plt.subplots()      # Initializes second plot\n",
ax2.plot(Vvals,J(Vvals), 'ro') # Creates linear plot\n",
ax2.set(xlabel='Voltage (V)', ylabel='Current Density J', title='Schottky diode J-V Linear')
plt.show()
```